# Unsure how I can mock an INancyModule.View method?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, nancy

I'm trying to mock an `INancyModule.View` method.

Here's my code (with the intellisense)

[image]

If I compile this, I get the following error compile time error:

> An expression may not contain a dynamic operation

Notice the intellisense? It's asking for a `dynamic` model. So I'm trying to pass that in, but it's not working.

Secondly, I'm trying to return a `ViewRenderer` but I'm not sure if that is setup correctly either.

So - how can I create a mock for an `INancyModule.View` property, please?

#### Update

Also, trying to replace `dynamic` with `object` has the following designer error... (please open the image up in another tab to read the error message).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible (with v0.23.2) and will require changes to Nancy in order to achieve mocking of the View so that a mock is returned rather than the implementation.